# Trying to understand Jquery appendTO

Tags: jquery

I am kind of new to Jquery and am trying to understand appendTo().

The problem is that when the form is submitted nothing is appended to the div. The code script works fine as long as no value is chosen, meaning the alert is triggered.

```
$('#blankett_form').submit(function() {
    var id = $(this).find('.update:last').val();
    if (id == '') {
        alert('Välj land och region.'); 
    } else {
        var table = '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"><thead><tr>    <td>blanketter.</td><td>datum tillagt.</td></tr></thead></table>'
        $(table).appendTo('#formsubmit');
    }
});
```

The table should be appended to the following div.

```
<div id="#formsubmit"> 

</div>
```

Comment: You mentioned a form being submitted. Is it possible the form is submitting and the page is reloading?

Comment: It is possible... The page is built in php and I did not think about that. Have to research it. Thank you.

Comment: put return false; right before the end of that script. The submit function is screwing it up, that and get rid of the # in the actual id name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the # from the div id `<div id="#formsubmit">`

```
<div id="formsubmit"> 

</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/9TNL4/)

or you have to escape the #

```
$(table).appendTo('#\\#formsubmit');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/LhKyv/)

As others mentioned if the form is being submitted then the page will probably refresh and you won't see any changes.

You can either return false or use [event.PreventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) inside the handler to stop the default submit action

```
$('#blankett_form').submit(function(e) { // <-- event argument passed in
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
     // your code here
}
```

or

```
$('#blankett_form').submit(function() {      
     // your code here
     return false;  
}
```

Comment: He's going to need to return false on the submit as well as this.

Comment: A new problem accrued when I did as you mentioned. every time the the submit button is pressed the "var" table is being appended. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: @StenW yes, you can do `$('#formsubmit').html(table)`.. or `$('#formsubmit').empty().append(table)`

Comment: Again: @wirey my dude of the day!